Can java get icons and their icon index from dll file?
Windows folder icon can be customized by specifying the icon file and icon index in Windows desktop.ini.
Take Documents as an example:
IconFile=%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll
IconIndex=-235

Now what I want to do:
When selecting a dll file in java, get icon list from the file like List<[Integer iconIndex, Icon iconImage]>.
Or make it simpler, just get a list like List<Integer iconIndex>.
If this is also difficult to implement, is it feasible only to shell32.dll?

You would have to parse the .dll file yourself.  Definitely difficult, though not impossible.  If you just want icons for file types, FileSystemView.getSystemIcon may meet your needs.
